# Unhandled Exception RDL

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I am new to SSRS, I was trying to deploy a report and am facing this unhandled exception

Unhandled exception:

> The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this
>   version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been
>   created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content
>   that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services
>   schemas. Details: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid
>   character. Line 3640, position 10.

I have opened RDL file with XML, based on the solution provided when I search I could not resolve the issues this id bugging me for the past 4 days

Any help any one, thanks

Comment: What are you using to deploy? What versions are you using for SQL Server and SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the same error when I tried to upload the report from the report manager.

First I got XML schema namespace error, to resolve that I've opened the RDL in Wordpad and changed the namespace & thats the mistake I've done. Wordpad tried to decode the RDL file in its way & it introduced some special characters. I should have used notepad or notepad++ to edit the namespace.
Also, if you're downgrading report remove 4 ReportSection XML tags from the RDL file.

I suggest if you have the physical RDL/RDLC file, open it with notepad to make relevant changes you need. I hope this helps.